# How to divide values of two columns with another name in sqlcontext?

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I have afile callled tagupdate(UserId,MovieId,Tag)and also I have table consists of (MovieId,Tag,occurrence,count)
change name of MovieId,Tag,occurrence as eachTagCount ,count as totalcount.
I want to divide value of eachTagCount/totalCount with new name as tagScore.
How to write this query?
val tagScore = sqlContext.sql("SELECT MovieId,Tag,(eachTagCount/totalCount) AS tagScore FROM finalresult")

val finalresult= sqlContext.sql("SELECT MovieId,Tag,occurrence AS eachTagCount, count AS totalCount FROM result ORDER BY MovieId")

```
finalresult.rdd
  .map(_.toSeq.map(_+"").reduce(_+","+_))
  .saveAsTextFile("/usr/local/spark/dataset/algorithm3/output5")
  case class fine(  MovieId:Int,Tag:String,occurrence:Int,count:Int)
  val Data5 = sc.textFile("file:///usr/local/spark/dataset/algorithm3/output5").map(_.split(",")).map(p => fine(p(0).trim.toInt,p(1),p(2).trim.toInt,p(3).trim.toInt)).toDF()
Data5.registerTempTable("finalresult")


  val tagScore = sqlContext.sql("SELECT MovieId,Tag,( eachTagCount / totalCount) AS tagScore FROM finalresult")

   tagScore.rdd
  .map(_.toSeq.map(_+"").reduce(_+","+_))
  .saveAsTextFile("/usr/local/spark/dataset/algorithm3/output6")
def main(args: Array[String]) {
     val ratings= sc.textFile("file:///usr/local/spark/dataset/tagupdate") 
   .map(line => line.split(";"))
     .map(userRecord => (userRecord(0),
     userRecord(1), userRecord(2),userRecord(3)))
     val ratingsRDD = sc.textFile("file:///usr/local/spark/dataset/tagupdate")

}
}
```

Exception

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Cannot resolve column name " eachTagCount";
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$resolve$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:152)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$resolve$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:152)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
```

Comment: can you show some input data and expected output? this is confusing reading the question

Comment: when writting this query val tagScore = sqlContext.sql("SELECT MovieId,Tag,(eachTagCount/totalCount) AS tagScore FROM finalresult") above exception appear

Comment: looking at your code your Data5 would in in the case class format  there you dont have any column called eachTagCount or totalCount. so naturally your select would fail.   if can you do a printschema and show on your Data5 you will see that those columns do not exists.  you will need to add that aggregation logic first.

Comment: It is one of steps but other stepshere
4. val orderedId = sqlContext.sql(“SELECT movieid AS id,
tag FROM tag ORDER BY movieid”)   5.val eachTagCount =
orderedId.groupBy(“id,tag”).count()
6. val finalresult = sqlContext.sql(“SELECT movieid,
tagname, occurrence AS eachTagCount, count AS
totalCount FROM result ORDER BY movieid”)
7. val tagScore = sqlContext.sql(“SELECT movieid,
tagname,(eachTagCount/totalCount) AS tagScore
FROM finalresult”))

Comment: is this your complete code or are there steps still missing?  in line 5 .. what is tag in your select statement  is tag another table or DF.. I do not see anything relating to that.   after each of your steps if you hit show you should be able to figure out where is your code breaking

Comment: just update your complete code in the example and give some test data so I can help you find where the issue lies .

Comment: full code is above ,can you help me please?@ Aaron

Comment: ilooked at your full code..  68 where you have val Data5 Statement.  you are reading the textfile and casting it to your fine case class.  the fine case class does not have member caleed eachTagCount or TotalCount. that is why your code throws error.  if your case class 3rd and 4th members , occurrence and count have the same data is eachTagCount and totalCount. then just change those names  in your select

Answer (score 2):

if you look at this part of your code

```
case class fine(  MovieId:Int,Tag:String,occurrence:Int,count:Int)
val Data5 = sc.textFile("file:///usr/local/spark/dataset/algorithm3  /output5").map(_.split(",")).map(p => fine(p(0).trim.toInt,p(1),p(2).trim.toInt,p(3).trim.toInt)).toDF()
Data5.registerTempTable("finalresult")
val tagScore = sqlContext.sql("SELECT MovieId,Tag,( eachTagCount / totalCount) AS tagScore FROM finalresult")
```

above Data5 is converted to the case class.. if you do printschema on data5 you will have something like this

```
|-- MovieId
|-- Tag
|-- occurrence
|-- count
```

when you register that as temp table and run select  obviously it will not find the columns eachTagCount and totalCount.  occurrence = eachTagCount and count = totalCount

then simply change your select statement to below

```
 val tagScore = sqlContext.sql("SELECT MovieId,Tag,(occurrence/count) AS tagScore FROM finalresult")
```

Hope that solves your issue 
also this is very inefficient way of writing your code. If you are learning than it is okay.. imho 
Tip
 you can just read files as csv  using spark.read.csv. this will eliminate the rdd.map process also for you writes you can use df.write.csv(path) also. would make your code a lot less convoluted.

Comment: you're welcome.. glad to help.. please accept the answer if it was satisfactory. Also I would recommend  that  you use the read and df.write methods that will reduce your code by 60 %. also, for each Df you need not have to define case class.. in your code they do next to nothing but create more confusion.